# Conditionally replace column items with contents of another column

Tags: awk, sed

I have financial price data in a csv file, a typical line of which looks like this:

```
2012-06-06 18:00:00,2012-06-06 19:00:00,4,2012-06-06 14:00:00,4,1644.8005,1644.8,1631.232,1632.266,7353,TRUE
```

and I would like to conditionally replace, in this particular example, the contents of column 7 with that of column 6 such that columns 6 and 7 both contain the same value.

The file line numbers on which such conditional operations should be completed are to be read from a separate text file ( let's call it "line_index_file" which is output from another program, Octave ) and this looks, for example, like this:

```
100
125
```

which means the above operations should only be applied to lines 100 and 125 of the original data file.

How would I do this with either sed or awk?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a {$7=$6}1' line_index_file file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for i in `cat line_index_file`
 do
     echo -e "`awk -v b=$i -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS = ","} NR!=b{$7=$6};{print $0}' file.csv`" > file.csv
 done
```

- `NR!=b` ignore the line numbers for the condition

Comment: This is not working for me. If I run it once only there are no problems, but if I then run a similar bash script with different values in a different line_index_file_2 and replacing different column's values, e.g. NR!=b{$8=$6}, the new values in the line_index_file_2 seem to be ignored and the original line_index_file values are used.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `sed` editor to do this task also:

```
cmds=$(< line_index_file xargs -l printf '\t%sba\n')

sed -e "
${cmds}
    ;# skip these
    b
    :a
    s/,/\n/5;s//\n/5;s//\n/5
    s/\n\(.*\)\n.*\n/,\1,\1,/
" input.csv
```

Explanation:

- First create a shell variable, `cmds`, holding the branching to the label `:a` information for the lines mentioned in the `line_index_file`.
- Skip processing the other lines, that is those lines that are not mentioned in line_index_file.
- Place a marker `\n` (since a newline is guaranteed to not be found in the pattern space of `sed` in our case) at the ending of 5th, 6th, and 7th fields.
- Then perform the operation to place the contents of the 6th field into the 7th.